# Statusbar Notification doesn't fit the screen Phonegap for Android

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, statusbar, word-wrap

I'm using Phonegap based statusbar notification plugin on my application, everything works fine except sometimes the text of the notification does not fit the screen and the app just shows three dots (see the picture below). Of course in landscape mode it shows the whole notification text, but I'm wondering if there any solution to display **really long** notification texts in portrait mode by dividing it into several lines? Or word-wrap method?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: currently thats not supported I guess.. Did you find any solution to your problem ?